# Is it possible to retrieve more information using jsoup when there is a button that gets more content?

Tags: android, jsoup

If a website displays a limited number of content and it has a button which will:

- Call more content;
- Not change current ones;
- Not change current url

Getting the first thing that goes on website is doable, but is it possible to get more content when you need to press the button to receive more info? And if it is possible, how could you retrieve the new information?

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's debugger (Network tab) to investigate what happens when you click the button.

- If it submits the form and gets the data from the response you can execute the same request  with the same parameters using jsoup and get the data directly.
- If it grabs some data using AJAX you can make the same request using Jsoup and parse the data (in this case the data may me JSON so you'll have to use another library to parse it).

Comment: What you said sounded very simple but i don't have knowledge to understand how to filter it. Can we talk in private about this?

Comment: Here's an example image explaining how to check how data is loaded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815619/how-to-extract-a-link-from-form-action-in-html-with-jsoup/54828795#54828795

Comment: Ok, we are going somewher, in case the link im trying to get more info is this https://www.ligapokemon.com.br/?view=cards/search&card=ed%3DVIV, and the button in the end is the one on quest. What was retrieved using your description was this https://ibb.co/CtKzc38. Can i make any use of it?